# Create Excel file from command line

Tags: excel, command, excel-2007

Is there any way to create a new Excel file from command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the Excel files you need to create are always the same, you can create a template manually, then create new files at will with something like...

```
copy template.xlsx myNewSpreadsheet.xlsx
```

If you need to create files with content that varies, I suggest starting with the powershell solution proposed by David.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using PowerShell:

```
PS> $excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
PS> $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
PS> $ws = $wb.ActiveSheet
PS> $excel.Visible = $True

       < do some work >

PS> $wb.SaveAs("xltest.xlsx")
PS> $wb.Close()
PS> $excel.Quit()
```