# Convert .TXT to .XSLX with keep data type of each cell "Text"

Tags: linux, shell

I have Tab separated CSV file, which I need to convert into .xlsx using shell script by keeping data type as "TEXT" for all columns.

I tried some "sed" commands but it does not work.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create excel file from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635434/create-excel-file-from-command-line)

Comment: You can use python pandas with dataframe [.to_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) method

Comment: @EPo I went through the link which you have shared, I can easily convert files from TXT to XLSX but how can I set data type as a "Text" to excel cells

Comment: Do you really mean `.xlsx` files, which are a special MS XML format or will a TSV `.xls` file do? If the latter, try a quick test with your data, by surrounding each field with dbl-quotes, i.e. `"data1"<TAB>"data2"<TAB>"data3"<TAB>123`, where of course `<TAB>` is just the single `\t` character. This used to work for me. There are other tricks for  forcing formatting in TSV files, but you'll have to do an internet search to find them. Good luck.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0):

If you import a csv to pandas and want to write to Excel as text format you can consider:

- Enforce string format on reading the file `pd.read_csv` (eg. with `dtype`), this 
  assures your dataframe contains strings
- Write to xlsx file with .to_excel() method, check cell type
- If cell type in xlsx is not string, see [column formatting](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html) and setting
  [string type](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/288#issuecomment-132485074).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think there is as much to discuss, but go ahead, there are my contacts at profile.